# How can i test the catch statement consisting of Promise.reject using mockRejectedValue or other mock functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios

This is my `application.tsx` file :

```
import axios from '../util/axios';

 

const fetchApplications = () => {
  return axios
    .get('/portal-appmanager/v1/applications', {
      responseType: 'json',
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};
```

This is my `application.test.tsx` file for testing the fetchApplication function:

```
import axios from '../util/axios';
jest.mock('../util/axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
import {
    fetchApplications,
  } from './application';

 

describe('Application tests', () => {
    it('/portal-appmanager/v1/applications - Test for fetchApplication', async () => {
      const expectedResult = {};
      mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: expectedResult } as any);
      await fetchApplications();
      expect(mockedAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
    it('test for catch block', () => {
        mockedAxios.get.mockRejectedValue('...');
        expect(mockedAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });    
});
```

How can I test catch statement that has **Promise.reject** in it ,I was unable to test it using `.mockRejectedValue` , I was unable to cover the code present in the catch statement.

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue but you are not calling the `await fetchApplications();` in your `test for catch block`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the main issue here is that `await fetchApplications()` isn't being called in your catch test, so although it does look like you are correctly mocking an Axios failure, you're not triggering the call to Axios in the `fetchApplications` code that you're testing.

It's worth considering whether this is worth implementing at all though, because your catch code doesn't actually do anything. This code:

```js
    .catch(error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

This is the same as the default behaviour (an error in the preceeding promise results in a rejected promise). It's doing nothing at all.

It's still good to test error cases of course, but if this were my code, I'd delete that catch completely and test error handling at a higher level of abstraction instead.

Comment: how can I test the code in catch if i want to improve my code coverage , using mockRejectedValue what changes should i make to the existing code, any suggestion?

Comment: Add `await fetchApplications()`, or remove the catch() completely.

Comment: I have added await fetchApplications(); but still unable to cover it.